# Videostream download via http get request

Tags: c#, html, video, stream, download

I´m trying to download a stream from streamcloud.eu
The page sends from the site [Streamcloud.eu](http://streamcloud.eu/skx06ayqai1v/Dr.House.S03E21.Auf.der.Kippe.GERMAN.WS.DVDRiP.XviD-SOF.avi.html)

a GET request which looks like this

```
GET /s3v75x75fwoax3ptxzginrpsu6hnbohophhebgisjj46deazergu4ll2ae/video.mp4?start=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: cdn2.streamcloud.eu:443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
Accept: */*
Referer: http://streamcloud.eu/skx06ayqai1v/Dr.House.S03E21.Auf.der.Kippe.GERMAN.WS.DVDRiP.XviD-SOF.avi.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: lang=german; afc=39448; __utma=5658353.378845871.1355854410.1362835465.1362845552.59; __utmb=5658353.3.10.1362845552; __utmc=5658353; __utmz=5658353.1362169689.44.17.utmcsr=kinox.to|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/Stream/Unstoppable-Ausser_Kontrolle.html
```

gets the file from the server (from google chrome).

Anyone knows how i can record the data with a c# client? raw bytes are enought!

Comment: I tried with WebClient and HttpClient
Any special things I have to consider when I use this class?
Could you give me a example how to use it with the get data?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx